# Algorithm for detecting combinations

Tags: algorithm, networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I am creating a simple intrusion detection system for an Information Security course using jpcap.

One of the features will be remote OS detection, in which I must implement an algorithm that detects when a host sends 5 packets within 20 seconds that have different ACK, SYN, and FIN combinations.

What would be a good method of detecting these different "combinations"? A brute-force algorithm would be time-consuming to implement, but I can't think of a better method.

Notes: jpcap's API allows one to know if the packet is ACK, SYN, and/or FIN. Also note that one doesn't need to know what ACK, SYN, and FIN are in order to understand the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry ... What is an ACK, SYN, and FIN combination?

Comment: Show some example, I can't understand exact problem.

Comment: Packets are being received by a program ("streamed" perhaps is a good word) that have a type of ACK, SYN, FIN, or any combination thereof. Essentially the question is, how can one detect when five different combinations have occurred?

Answer (score 0):

I built my own data structure based on vectors that hold "records" about the type of packet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep state on each session. - using hashtables.  Keep each syn,ack and fin/fin-ack. I wrote and opensource IDS sniffer a few years ago that does this; feel free to look at the code.   It should be very easy to write an algorithm to do passive os-detection (google it).   My opensource code is here [dnasystem](http://dnasystem.sourceforge.net)